# Adding MSCRM.SuppressDuplicateDetection header to CRM Dynamics Web API request gives HTTP 412 code

Tags: rest, odata, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-webapi

We are using the WEB API of Microsoft CRM Dynamics online (v9.0)

Everything works fine with 'normal' create en read operations but when we want to use the duplication detection feature, the Microsoft webservice returns with 412.

```
URL obj = new URL(fullOdataURL);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");

con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accesstoken);
con.setRequestProperty("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
con.setRequestProperty("OData-Version", "4.0");
con.setRequestProperty("MSCRM.SuppressDuplicateDetection", "false");
```

In the CRM web UI, the duplicate detection works, see screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) `412 Precondition Failed` client error response code indicates that access to the target resource has been denied. This happens with conditional requests on methods other than `GET` or `HEAD` when the condition defined by the `If-Unmodified-Since` or `If-None-Match` headers is not fulfilled. In that case, the request, usually an upload or a modification of a resource, cannot be made and this error response is sent back.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/412)

So, in your request add this below header:

```
If-None-Match: null
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/manage-duplicate-detection-create-update)

```
con.setRequestProperty("If-None-Match", null);
```